# which is the different between openstack-charmers and openstack-charmers-next?

Tags: juju

someone knows why in juju store is present the same bundle created by openstack-charmers or openstack-charmers-next? which is the different?

[image]
[image]

Just to know which bundle I've to deploy.

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue..? I am facing similar issue. I used conjure-up openstack with kvm . Openstack got deployed with out any issue, but my networking got messed up. No internet in the VM's and also not able to ping the VM from outside n/w but can ping from Openstack Router. 
Any leads would be really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[openstack-charmers](https://jujucharms.com/u/openstack-charmers/) is the namespace for stable OpenStack charms and bundles (see their [release policy](https://docs.openstack.org/charm-guide/latest/release-policy.html)).

[openstack-charmers-next](https://jujucharms.com/u/openstack-charmers-next) on the other hand is the namespace for development charms and bundles.